# Call aspx event handler with http request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

Consider the following code from behind an aspx page:

```
protected void onBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Is it possible to create/craft a `POST` request (HTTPWebRequest/HttpClient) to call the event handler behind of the aspx page ?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly - you'll need some kind of a web service frontend, e.g. ASP.NET MVC or a web service method on an old legacy `.asmx` or WCF service. ASP.NET Webforms (`.aspx`) doesn't really have any capability to be called from the outside

Comment: It's not possible because what that event handler needs/expects is loads of context about the state of the page on which the button was clicked. There's no direct URL which will point to that method. It's all tied up in asp.net webforms' page lifecycle (which is a nasty, complicated beast that was always unsuited to the web application environment into which it was shoehorned (copied from desktop winforms). As marc_s says, you need a separate web service of some sort. ASP.NET offers a whole menu of choices on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I was able to get this to work, but it takes specific changes to your .aspx page that you probably do not want to do (or cant do): `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false"` also have to set your ClientIDMode to static

Given this `Test.aspx` webform markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="OnClick" Text="Click Me" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Button1" />
</form>
```

And this codebehind:

```
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("clicked");
}
```

I was able to post to Test.aspx from an arbitrary html page (same site) and have `OnClick` fire, also `Page.IsPostBack` was set to `true`:

```
<form method="post" action="Test.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="Button1" value="Click+Me" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Again, this is not recommended, probably opens Test.aspx up to all kinds of nasty hacks.